# Pandas Top n % of grouped sum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, percentile

I work for a company and am trying to calculate witch products produced the top 80% of Gross Revenue in different years.

Here is a short example of my data:

```
Part_no Revision    Gross_Revenue   Year
1            a          1           2014
2            a          2           2014
3            c          2           2014
4            c          2           2014
5            d          2           2014
```

I've been looking through various answers and here's the best code I can come up with but it is not working:

```
df1 = df[['Year', 'Part_No', 'Revision', 'Gross_Revenue']]
df1 = df1.groupby(['Year', 'Part_No','Revision']).agg({'Gross_Revenue':'sum'})
# print(df1.head())
a = 0.8
df2 = (df1.sort_values('Gross_Revenue', ascending = False)
                .groupby(['Year', 'Part_No', 'Revision'], group_keys = False)
                .apply(lambda x: x.head(int(len(x) * a )))
                .reset_index(drop = True))
print(df2)
```

I'm trying to have the code return, for each year, all the top products that brought in 80% of our company's revenue.

I suspect it's the old 80/20 rule.

Thank you for your help,
Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `cumsum`

```
df[df.groupby('Year').Gross_Revenue.cumsum().div(df.groupby('Year').Gross_Revenue.transform('sum'),axis=0)<0.8]
Out[589]: 
   Part_no Revision  Gross_Revenue  Year
1        2        a              2  2014
2        3        c              2  2014
3        4        c              2  2014
```